# "Hub" which executes interface methods on all registered instances

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have a generic class (let's name it `Hub`) which implements:
- interface `T`
- has method named `Add` (not a part or interface `T`)
And now calling `Add` allows me to store any instance of `T` in internal list.

And finally when I use a method `XYZ` from interface `T` on my `Hub` class, for example: `Hub.XYZ(1)`, it will fire a method `XYZ` with parameter `1` on all instances registered in my internal list.

Example:

```
var hub = Hub<IDisposable>();
hub.Add (new SomeClassA());
hub.Add (new SomeClassB());
hub.Add (new SomeClassC());

hub.Dispose(); // it will call Dispose on all 3 registered instances
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to construct class which behave like i descirbed.

Comment: Yes, but plain old C# delegates already do this.

Comment: @Telastyn is right.  Plus, of course, almost anything is possible in simple C# code, even if it's already baked into the language and CLR.

Comment: And how to do it?

Comment: BTW, I think a better name for your `Hub` would be [`Composite`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it using exactly this syntax, because generic parameters can't change what interfaces does your class implement (i.e. you can't write something like `class Hub<T> : T`).

I can see two alternative ways to do this (there are probably others):

**A simple approach using lambdas**

Your `Hub` class would have a method like `void Execute(Action<T> action)`, which would execute the given `action` for all items in it.

With this, your code would become:

```
var hub = new Hub<IDisposable>();

hub.Add(new SomeClassA());
hub.Add(new SomeClassB());
hub.Add(new SomeClassC());

hub.Execute(x => x.Dispose());
```

The implementation of `Hub` could look something like:

```
public class Hub<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Execute(Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**A complicated approach using metaprogramming, that results in a slightly simpler syntax**

Another way would be to have a property of the interface type on your `Hub`, which would actually return a type generated at runtime that executes the action for all items. To generate such type, you could use something like [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), or do it manually using Reflection.Emit.

With this, your code would look like this:

```
var hub = new Hub<IDisposable>();

hub.Add(new SomeClassA());
hub.Add(new SomeClassB());
hub.Add(new SomeClassC());

hub.Instance.Dispose();
```

The code for `Hub` using DynamicProxy is actually simpler than I expected:

```
public class Hub<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly List<T> items;
    private readonly T instance;

    public Hub()
    {
        items = new List<T>();
        var interceptor = new HubInterceptor(items);
        instance = new ProxyGenerator().CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<T>(interceptor);
    }

    public T Instance { get { return instance; } }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }

    private class HubInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<T> targets;

        public HubInterceptor(IEnumerable<T> targets)
        {
            this.targets = targets;
        }

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            foreach (var target in targets)
            {
                invocation.Method.Invoke(target, invocation.Arguments);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# delegates already do this.

```
var hub = Action<int>();
hub += new SomeClassA().XYZ;
hub += new SomeClassB().XYZ;
hub += new SomeClassC().XYZ;
hub(1);
```

Better yet, you don't actually need the different classes to have a common interface. As long as you specify some function that takes an `int` and returns `void` then `Action<int>` works.

The problem with this implementation is that the functions are executed in order. If an exception happens in one, the chain stops, and you don't know where. The alternative is to build a class that keeps the delegates(or an instance of your interface) in a list, calling them in turn.

Comment: I assumed that the hub should work even for interfaces with more than one method.